# c# unit test override method

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am relatively new to Unit testing and I was wondering if there is a built in solution for the following problem.

I want to test a method which at one point measures some input from a hardware.

```
var results = Measurement.MeasureAll();
```

I want of course to test this without the hardware. Is there a way to override somehow for the scope of the unit test the Measurement.MeasureAll(); method to return some predefined values?

Comment: You want to program to interfaces not to concrete implementation. With that you could easily provide your own test-only implementation

Comment: This question is far too broad. You have to provide some code first. Basically you want to create some interfaces for which can provide some dummy-implementations that mock your hardware. However if your method is static there is no way on doing this, you can only mock virtual members. (and interface-members of course).

Comment: You should also look at Microsoft's unit testing framework [Fakes] https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx. If you do not have a choice of altering implementation you can shim the MeasureAll method call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would mock the dependency.  This is your dependency:

```
Measurement
```

What is `Measurement`?  Where does it come from?  In order to make the code unit-testable, `Measurement` should be supplied to that code.  Something like this:

```
public void MethodBeingTested(Measurement measurement)
{
    // use Measurement here
}
```

Or maybe this:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private Measurement TheMeasurement { get; set; }

    public SomeClass(Measurement theMeasurement)
    {
        TheMeasurement = theMeasurement;
    }

    public void MethodBeingTested()
    {
        // use TheMeasurement here
    }
}
```

Then your unit tests can create a fake/mock/stub/etc. `Measurement` and supply that to the tests.  (There are tons of mocking libraries available to help with this.  I personally like Moq and RhinoMocks.)  That "mock" version would be defined by the tests to perform in a specific and predictable way.  It would then observe that the code being tested interacted with the mock in exactly the way that was expected.

---

Now, some objects are notoriously difficult to mock.  **This can *especially* be the case if what you're showing us is `static`.**  (Static members make unit tests notoriously difficult.)  This is where you would wrap such an object in a mockable wrapper which *can* be mocked.  Something as simple as this:

```
public interface IMeasurement
{
    SomeType MeasureAll();
}

public class MyMeasurement
{
    // declare Measurement here?  some other context?

    public SomeType MeasureAll()
    {
        return Measurement.MeasureAll();
    }
}
```

The idea here is that your business logic would couple to `IMeasurement`, over which you have complete control and mockability/testability.  Then you could supply a mocked version of the wrapper class (made trivial by the use of an interface) and not have to worry about mocking the actual dependency.

Comment: Unfortunately it is a static class (Measurement) which I am calling here. Let me see if I understand you correctly. The correct way, is to create a wrapper class MyMeasurement for the static class, and give it over to my method I want to Unit test. And in the unit test I simply give my mock class as parameter, which instead of the douing the original MeasureAll(), does whatever I wish it to?

Comment: @TamaskaJanos: All the more reason to use a wrapper in this case, then.  Unit tests become a lot simpler with instance members than with static members.  The wrapper can be instance-based and can internally use the static members of the dependency.

Comment: Let me see if I understand you correctly. The correct way, is to create a wrapper class MyMeasurement for the static class, and give it over to my method I want to Unit test. And in the unit test I simply give my mock class as parameter, which instead of the douing the original MeasureAll(), does whatever I wish it to?

Comment: @TamaskaJanos: That's how I'd do it in this case.  (Barring any other concerns not noted here in the question, of course.)  There may be more than one way, I won't pretend that mine is the only possible approach.  But in my experience wrappers like this greatly simplify testing.  The trade-off is that you don't reach 100% code coverage because you still can't test the wrapper itself.  But the wrapper is just a pass-through, it doesn't have any logic to meaningfully test.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll give it a go!